# Stuck with programming AVR ATMEGA128

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, atmega

I'm trying to build my first program in C for ATMEGA128 microcontroller and I have a problem with buttons. I need to light LEDs in particular order and using a button I need to be able to change the direction on the opposite direction (like on the picture
[lights order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4x6l.png) )
Now the problem is that when using a button I can't just press it. It needs to be held in order to change the direction of lights. I tried some things, but nothing worked. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is my code in C:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
DDRA = 0xFF;
PORTA = 0b00000001; 
DDRB = 0xFF;
PORTB = 0x00;
DDRD = 0xFF;
PORTD = 0b10000000;
DDRC = 0xFF;
PORTC = 0x00;
DDRE = 0x00;
PORTE = 0xFF;

while(1)
{
    int E;
    int d;
    d = 500;
    E = PINE&(1<<PE0);
    if (E==1)
    {
        
        for (int i=7; i>=0; i--)
        {
            PORTA = (1<<i);
            PORTD = (1<<(7-i));
            _delay_ms(d);
        }
        PORTA &=~ (1<<0);
        PORTD &=~ (1<<7);
        PORTC |= (1<<7);
        PORTB |= (1<<0);
        _delay_ms(d);
        PORTC &=~ (1<<7);
        PORTB &=~ (1<<0);
        PORTB |= (1<<7);
        PORTC |= (1<<0);
        _delay_ms(d);
        PORTB &=~ (1<<7);
        PORTC &=~ (1<<0);
        
    }
    
    else
    {
        
        for (int i=0;i<=7;i++)
        {
            PORTA = (1<<i);
            PORTD = (1<<(7-i));
            _delay_ms(d);
        }
        PORTA &=~ (1<<7);
        PORTD &=~ (1<<0);
        PORTB |= (1<<7);
        PORTC |= (1<<0);
        _delay_ms(d);
        PORTB &=~ (1<<7);
        PORTC &=~ (1<<0);
        PORTC |= (1<<7);
        PORTB |= (1<<0);
        _delay_ms(d);
        PORTC &=~ (1<<7);
        PORTB &=~ (1<<0);
        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what are the LEDs? What the buttons? No one knows how the hardware is designed so no one can help you

Comment: First of all, change your approach to a state machine with one calling to delay function. Inrease or decrease state variable depend on direction. Second, replace delay call by a custom function that tests button release and measures time at the same time. Each time you release the button, change direction.

Answer (score 1):

My answer depends on how you want to approach this and what peripherals you intend to use.

First of all i will assume that the button is currently connected to PORTE0.

If you want to stay on the quick and easy path and are ok with a little latency you can simply toggle a bit and wait for a short time instead of continuos polling.

to achive that you could use something like this intstead of your "E = PINE&(1<<PE0);"

```
if (PINE&(1<<PE0)) 
{
   E^=1; 
   _delay_ms(x)
}
```

You can also take that approach and make it better.
That delay to prevent double inputs in the if adds latency. If you do not want that you can "outsource" that delay to one of the onboard Timer/Conter modules. The [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc2467.pdf) has some nice diagramms and some examples on that topic (Page 92+)

My personal recomendation however is that you change the button from PORTE0 to a pin in PORTE 4-7. These can be configured as external interrupt sources (INT4-7). After the right configuration your Interrupt-Service-Routine could be nearly as simple as

```
ISR_INT4()
{
   E^=1; 
}
```

and you dont need to poll at all.

But if you use that approach dont forget to declare your variable E as volatile. You ned that because Interrupts are considered to be external operations.

As you can see you have many possibilities to make that work. You can choose one based on what peripherals you can use or feel comfortable using.
If you have chosen an approach that suits you and you have further questions regarding that approach feel free to comment here. I hope i remember to check back in one or two days.

Best regards
Stromi

Comment: How you will debounce ISR approach? How you will react if button will be pushed in middle for cycle?

Comment: With that direct approach directly it will continue that cycle and change direction when the next cycle starts. That could be circumvented if you change your code. Right now it checks E and does a full cycle. if you change that to that it only does one shift (conditional on E -right/left and minor exeptions for PORTB/C) and checks E again it will be faster.     The debouncing is a very valid point. Since we already have delays i suggest disabeling the interuppt in the ISR and re-enabeling it after the delay. To prevent the eventuality that the delay-TImer is just about ready you can reset that